# Removing dependencies from statechart framework

Tags: c++, design-patterns, architecture, refactoring, state-pattern

I've got lots of problems with project i am currently working on. The project is more than 10 years old and it was based on one of those commercial C++ frameworks which were very populary in the 90's. The problem is with statecharts. The framework provides quite common implementation of state pattern. Each state is a separate class, with action on entry, action in state etc. There is a switch which sets current state according to received events.

Devil is hidden in details. That project is enormous. It's something about 2000 KLOC. There is definitely too much statecharts (i've seen "for" loops implemented using statecharts). What's more ... framework allows to embed statechart in another statechart so there are many statecherts with seven or even more levels of nesting. Because statecharts run in different threads, and it's possible to send events between statecharts we have lots of synchronization problems (and big mess in interfaces).

I must admit that scale of this problem is overwhelming and I don't know how to touch it. My first idea was to remove as much code as I can from statecharts and put it into separate classes. Then delegate these classes from statechart to do a job. But in result we will have many separate functions, which logically don't have any specific functionality and any change in statechart architecture will need also a change of that classes and functions.

So I asking for help:
Do you know any books/articles/magic artefacts which can help me to fix this ? I would like to at least separate as much code as I can from statechart without introducing any hidden dependencies and keep separated code maintainable, testable and reusable.

If you have any suggestion how to handle this, please let me know.

Comment: This system didn't happen by accident. Somebody built it in a way that worked for them that you don't understand; you better figure that out. So was this system built using statechart editor/code generator? If you've lost that, you've lost the actual source code; what you're working on is "object code" compiled by the generator. Or are all these statecharts generated by hand? How do you know? (Doomed indeed :)

Comment: ... on thinking about this, I wonder if the problem is really statecharts They're just a way of organizing control, much like if statements and while loops, with the added advantage of allowing parallelism in sub-charts. This should be *helpful* in understanding how the the code works; you could be coding this stuff with just "low-level C++" constructs, which is kind of like coding structured control flow using just gotos. Unless the original coders were complete dolts, they likely understood this flow the same way you understand structured control flow.

Comment: ira baxter: there is a graphic tool for statechart design, and statecharts are stored in some kind of pseudo code. The first thing is that it's not possible to keep that files in svn as text files, because merge just doesn't work for them. And the second: unfortunately this tool was used in a wrong way. Developers and architect were learning this tool during the first, most important phase of architecture design and implementation of app skeleton. Now we have interfaces based on framework dependent events and code is not portable at all.

Comment: for 2 MSLOC worth of code?  That's a pretty big chunk of stuff for people to not have learned how to use their tools.  As a general rule when facing a big system, you should be charitable towards the original designers. They probably were smart, and likely had some idea of what they intended and even achieved it to some extent.  You're the guy with the lack of understanding here, or at least that's the bet you should make unless you really, really know what you are doing.    It could be they're all screwed up.  But if they were organized, and you don't see how, you're the one that gets hurt.

Comment: Your remark about "can't store in svn as text files"... so what? You can still store them. Doesn't matter if they aren't text; what matters is that they represent some of your code structure and until you are sure you can throw they away, you shouldn't do that. (The fact that you are thinking like this suggests you aren't really, really sure of what you are doing). YMMV.

Comment: If the code really is generated by a tool then it's highly likely that a lot of it is bloated and difficult to follow. I've yet to see an auto-code-generation which works much beyond the first architectural stab in the dark (having said that though, I'd love to be proven wrong)! If that was the leaping off point and 40 developers then hacked at the codeface to try and shape it into something workable.. ...well good luck!

Comment: @Baxter: Do you have anything _constructive_ to add to help the OP here?

Comment: @jon: Yes. I said he should keep the state chart data he was given, and he should investigate the state charts tools that were used to build the system.   If he throws those away NOW in his hurry to fix something, he'll never be able to pick them up later.  He will be doomed to staring at the generated code, which I suspect is bloated and difficult to follow. Its like staring at object code; we both agree that's hard. The point is that this system was apparantly programmed in StateCharts with some C++.  Maybe the statechart stuff is a mess, but OP seems to want to toss it without investigation

Comment: @jon: *If* he has investigated the state charts thouroughly, and is convinced they are truly not worth bits they are written on, then he has some justification for abandoning them.  I didn't hear any strong evidence he had done that.  He's welcome to say so and then the conversation might turn in another direction.

Comment: @Ira: Fair point. I've not heard any strong evidence the other way either mind you...

Answer (score 1):

The statechart pattern is intended to be used specifically to remove switch statements, so this sounds like a horrid abuse.  Additionally, states should only change on asynchronous events.  If you are processing an event and you change through multiple states (or for loop, etc.), then this is also a horrid abuse of the pattern.

I would start from these two points, as they will solve much of your concurrency issues just fixing them up.  What you need to determine is:

1. What are your external, asynchronous events to the system?  These are the only things that should be determining state transitions, not things that happen during event processing.  An event may cause 0 or 1 state transitions.  Once you have a list of these state transitions, you can reconstruct the actual states of your system.  If you are aware of UML State diagrams, this would be a perfect time to sketch one up in a charting program, not just for yourself (though it will help you immensely), but also for everyone in the future that has to return to the project.  As you have learned, this happens.
2. Now that you know what are really states, list what are states in the code that shouldn't be.  This usually indicates that something can be "functionally decomposed".  Instead of a state object for each of these, likely all that is needed is a separate function.  This will cut down on a lot of the overhead of state objects and should clean up the code immensely.
3. Now it's time to tackle those horrendous switch statements you mentioned.  If they were truly based on state, you shouldn't need one at all.  Instead, you should be able to call the state machine directly.

Something like:

```
myStateMachine->myEvent();
```

and it should work without any switch.  But notice, this may be the case even for some of those objects that don't work across asynchronous events.  This is also an indication of where you may just use inheritance to get the same effect.  If you have:

```
switch (someTypeIdentifier)
{
case type1:
  doSomething();
  break;

case type2:
  doSomethingElse();
  break;
}
```

usually the correct OOP method to do is to create two actual types Type1, Type2, both derived from an *abstract* base TypeBase, with a virtual method doSomething() that does what you need.  The reason this is useful is because it means you can "close" the handling (in the meaning of the Open/Closed Principle), and still extend the functionality by adding new derived types as needed (leaving it open to extension).  This saves bugs like crazy because it gets developers hands out of those switch statements, which can get quite ugly and convoluted, instead encapsulating each separate behavior in separate classes.

4 - Now look to fix up your thread issues.  Identify all objects used from multiple threads.  Make a list.  Now, how are these used?  Are some of them always used together?  Start making groups.  The goal here is to find the level of encapsulation that best works for these objects, separate the objects into individual classes that control their own synchronisation, figure out the atomic level of actual "transactions" for the objects, and make methods of the classes that expose those meaningful transactions, wrapped behind the scenes with the appropriate mutexes, condition variables, etc.

You might be saying "that sounds like a lot of work!  Why do all that instead of just writing it all over myself?"  Good question!  :)  The reason is actually straightforward: if you are going to do it all by yourself, those are the steps you should be doing anyway.  You should be identifying your states, your dynamic polymorphism, and getting a handle on the multithreaded transactions.  But, if you start with the existing code, you also have all of those unspoken business rules that were never documented and may cause all sorts of unexpected bugs down the line.  You don't have to bring everything over - if you suspect it's a bug, discuss the logic with the people who have worked with the system in the past (if available), QA, or whoever might identify bugs, and see if it really should be carried over.  But you need to actually evaluate what the bugs are either way, or you may not code something that actually needed coding.

In the end, this is a manual process that is a part of software engineering.  There are CASE tools that can help draw up the state diagrams and even publish them to code, there are refactoring tools, like those found in many IDEs, that can help move code between functions and classes, and similar tools which can help identify threading needs.  However, those things shouldn't be picked up for a single project.  They need to be learned throughout your career, picking them up and learning them more deeply over years of work, as they are a part of being a software engineer.  They don't do it for you.  You still need to know the whys and hows, and they just help get it done more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like your best bet is (gulp!) likely to start from scratch if it's as horrifically broken as you make out. Is there any documentation? Could you begin to build some saner software based on the docs?

If a complete re-write isn't an option (and they never are in my experience) I'd try some of the following:

1. If you don't already have it, draw an architectural picture of the whole system. Sketch out how all the bits are *supposed* to work together and that will help you break the system down into potentially manageable / testable parts.
2. Do you have any kind of requirements or testing plan in place? If not, can you write one and start to put unit tests in place for the various chunks of code / functionality which exist already? If you can do that, you can start to refactor things without breaking as much of whatever *does* currently work.
3. Once you've broken things down a bit, start building your unit tests into integration tests which pull together more of the functionality.

I've not read them myself, but I've heard good things about these books which may have some advice you can use:

1. [Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code (Object Technology Series)](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/0201485672).
2. [Working Effectively with Legacy Code (Robert C. Martin)](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Working-Effectively-Legacy-Robert-Martin/dp/0131177052/ref=pd_sim_b_3)

Good luck! :-)

Comment: Start from Scratch with 2 M SLOC?  Are you insane?

Comment: Basically, this is the way we are trying to follow. Quality of the unit and module tests is poor, but we started the refactoring project from test improvements. It consumes lot of resources to write a tests which covers all requirements in 2000000-line-of-code project, but if you have requirements and tests, why not to rewrite all from scratch :) ? The resource allocation for that task is critical for me. I have only four guys who try to fix code previously developed by 40 developers. Thank you for the books suggestions.

Comment: Do you *really* have the requirements, or just some dusty paper about what people thought the problem was 5 years ago? Assume your code base is 50% junk, and you only need 1 MSLOC code. At 50 lines of debugged code a day (you can do better? Not what Capers Jones says) you only need 1000000/50 -> 20,000 man days or 10 man-years. You got a year and 10 people? 6 months and 20 people? Wait, you have *4* people, OK, 2.5 years? People that attempt complete rewrites usually fail, if nothing else because managment pulls the plug after far too long a period.

Comment: Just because there's 2M SLOC doesn't mean it's all used, that there isn't massive duplication and it certainly doesn't mean it's right. The OP gave me the impression he wanted to do it right and if it's as broken as he makes out then that probably _is_ the best course of action. The number of developers and/or a specific time limit really doesn't make a difference if you're trying to do it _right_...

Comment: ..._but_, sometimes there's no right answer (at least with the time scales and resources available). Sometimes you have to make the best you can of a bad situation and in that case, I agree; starting from scratch is likely to ultimately finish with an incomplete product. Fixing the codebase as best he can is likely to end up with a product which appears more complete on the surface but is likely full of bugs.

Comment: Capers Jones has hard numbers on why (re)writing a big system is expensive. "(Software) Physics: its the law."  Spolsky has intuition: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html   Sometimes there is no right thing to do. But often there are very wrong things to do.

Comment: That's more like it; some constructive information - thanks for the info. I still maintain that there _are_ some (extreme) circumstances where the codebase is so broken and/or poorly documented that it would take as long to understand and correct issues as it would be to start afresh. The OP gave the impression that he has no idea how things work, that there are masses of bugs and that he didn't know how to progress. I simply offered two alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Statecharts (including nested Statecharts) are a powerful way to specify, understand and even simulate/validate complex control flow. But to gain the benefit, you need the statechart model in a suitable tool (I used Statemate way back in the day, not sure if it's still available), plus a reliable mapping from the chart to the code (Statemate used to generate the code) - then you can forget about the state management code (mostly)! In your situation, if you don't have the model, I would try to reverse one from the code - as Ira says, chances are high that the original developers had a model in some form, and you may find the code making a lot of sense as the model emerges. If this works out, you will have a really good spec/model of the code which should make future code edits much easier (even if you don't want to go to automatic code generation, and maintain the code/model mapping manually (but you'll need to be meticulous!!))